# Solve $3sec^2(x)=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $3sec^2(x)=4$.

$sec^2(x)=\frac{4}{3}$

$sec(x)=4=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}$

How to continue, i.e. how to calculate the value of x for which $sec(x)=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}$

I can rearrange the expression above into $cos(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$, but how to continue to find x?

Comment: Can you write $\sec$ in terms of other trig functions (like $\sin$, $\cos$ etc.)?

Comment: Square root of $\frac43$ is $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$

Answer (score 1):

The solution you've posted has some errors .It should be $\sec^2(x) = \frac{4}{3}$ and $\sec(x) = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$. Later on you can find the general solutions for x .

Comment: Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. I have edited your answer to make it more presentable.

Answer (score 0):

Given $$3\sec^2 x=4$$ $$\sec^2 x=\frac{4}{3}$$
$$\cos^2 x=\frac{3}{4}$$ $$\cos^2 x=\cos^2\frac{\pi}{6}$$
Writing the general solution, one gets 
$$\color{blue}{x=k\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}}$$
Where, $\color{blue}{k}$ is any interger

Answer (score 0):

For squares of any trigonometric function, find double angle of cosine.

$$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=2\cdot\dfrac34-1=\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3$$

$$\implies2x=2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3$$ where $m$ is any integer